# matlab cell array, count number of different elements

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have 2 cell arrays as below:

```
A = {'S' 'M' 'N' 'E'};
B = {'E' 'M' 'Q' 'S'};
```

In this case, the number of different elements is 3.

In a number array, I can use `length(find(A ~= B));` to easily count number of different elements in one step easily.

Is there something similar for cell array of characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT: I think I've misunderstood your question, and you probably meant finding different elements in corresponding positions in the arrays. I still kept my old answer*

#### Counting different elements at the same position

yuk's approach with `strcmp` is correct. However, it works only if the two arrays are of the same size. The generalized solution would be:

```
N = min(numel(A), numel(B));
sum(~strcmp(A(1:N), B(1:N))) + numel(A) + numel(B) - 2 * N
```

If the arrays are of different length, the "extra" elements in the larger array will be counted as different here.

#### Counting different elements in any position

The most general approach would be using `ismember`, which does not care about lengths of strings or their position in the array. To count the total number of elements in `A` and `B` that are different, just do:

```
sum(ismember(A, B)) + sum(ismember(B, A))
```

The same effect can also be obtained with [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) (instead of `ismember`):

```
numel(setdiff(A, B)) + numel(setdiff(B, A))
```

Both ways are valid for any two arrays, not necessarily of equal size.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
cell2mat(A)==cell2mat(B)
```

to start with, the rest should be straightforward.  This simple approach will fail if the cell arrays don't have the same dimensions.

Comment: `length(find(A ~= B));` would also fail if A and B have different number of elements so this sounds like the correct approach to me. +1

Comment: Yep, it works as expected, although I need to modify it a bit to use ~= since I want to find difference

Comment: This will work only if all strings in A and B are single-character.

Answer (score 2):

If your cell array is a cell array of strings you can use STRCMP:

```
sum(~strcmp(A,B))
```

Of course make sure `A` and `B` have the same length.

---

By the way for numeric array it's more efficient to use `sum(A~=B)`. In general `find` is slow.

Answer (score 0):

U can also try unique([A B]) if A and B are given in the exemple you gave.
It A and B do not have the same dimension you can try this.

unique(reshape(cell2mat(A,1,[])),reshape(cell2mat(B,1,[])))